# Black-Litterman risk aversion

Tags: black-litterman

I'm trying to better understand how BL works and what I would like to know if there is a way to adjust the portfolio created based on a risk aversion variable determined by the user.
I can't really find anything related to this, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

intuitively BL works as assuming return (can be factor return defined in APT model or return over some interval) follows normal distribution with mean $E$ and variance $V$, we want to infer such mean and variance based on noisy observations from view about portfolio, and then use mean variance optimization to get the optimal portfolio holding which is just $(kV[r])^{-1}E[r]$, $k$ being your risk aversion variable. So yes there is a way to adjust the portfolio based on it.

Comment: "your" risk aversion variable or "the markets'" risk aversion variable?

Comment: hmm good question, imho I would say in some ways a combination. One case might be a PM want to construct a portfolio with average holdings to be a certain number and thus $k$ is solved using both market info and his expectation